# More Efficient Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I'm playing around with a problem at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/angry-children.  I have written a solution that correctly solves some test cases.  Other test cases, cases that provide way more input, time out.  How can I change this code to process quicker?

```
N = int(input())
K = int(input())
D = K - 1
N_set = []
for n in range(N):
    N_set.append(int(input()))
N_set.sort(reverse=True)

#Find differences between each integer in the list
D_set = []
for d in range(0,N-1):
    D_set.append(N_set[d]-N_set[d+1])

D_Start = 0
D_End = D
min_summed_diff = 99999999999999
D_Start_Hold = None
D_End_Hold = None

count_down = len(D_set) - D + 1
while count_down:
    #print(count_down)
    temp_summed_diff = 0
    for i in range(D_Start, D_End):
        temp_summed_diff += D_set[i]

    if temp_summed_diff < min_summed_diff:
        min_summed_diff = temp_summed_diff
        D_Start_Hold = D_Start
        D_End_Hold = D_End

    D_Start += 1
    D_End += 1
    count_down -= 1

K_set = N_set[D_Start_Hold:D_End_Hold+1]
unfairness = max(K_set) - min(K_set)
print(unfairness)
```

Comment: Run it under `cProfile` and see what sticks out?

Answer (score 0):

The two initial loops will be faster is the method loopup is pulled out of the loop.  A list comprehension is also faster.  I ran this experiment

```
from timeit import timeit

a = '''\
tem = []
for i in range(%d):
  tem.append(int('1000'))
'''

b = '''\
tem = []
temapp = tem.append
for i in range(%d):
  temapp(int('1000'))
'''

c = "tem = [int('1000') for i in range(%d)]"

for n in (10,1000, 1000000):
    number = 1000000 // n
    print(timeit(a%n, number = number))
    print(timeit(b%n, number = number))
    print(timeit(c%n, number = number))
    print()
```

with these results.

```
0.48560521545219426
0.3943799918166562
0.4146867965037263

0.372683063890642
0.3126639858171769
0.2900946187597775

0.36497313668305287
0.33567233916055894
0.3071572902003692
```

I believe this sum

```
    temp_summed_diff = 0
    for i in range(D_Start, D_End):
        temp_summed_diff += D_set[i]
```

is just this, which will be faster

```
    temp_summed_diff = sum(D_set[D_start:D_end]
```

I do not see any other speedups.

Comment: If your code is correct and hackerrank does not multiply the max allowed running fime for Python, compared to C, by at least 20, I would move on.  Python was designed to minimize (expensive) programmer time, not (cheap) machine time.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm for calculating the minimum unfairness can be greatly improved.

If your list is sorted, then the unfairness of each sub list is just the difference between its ends, so it all boils down to finding the minimum of that difference for all sub lists of length k.

Also, in this kind of situations its usually faster to avoid `input()` and read directly from `sys.stdin`.

This whole problem can be solved in just 6 lines of python:

```
import sys
nrs = map(int, sys.stdin)
n, k = next(nrs), next(nrs)
nrs = sorted(nrs)
min_unfair = min(nrs[k+i-1] - nrs[i] for i in range(0, len(nrs)-k+1))
print(min_unfair)
```